# Problems setting values to an object of class created from json

Tags: c#, json

I had a json file and I converted it to a class file like this :

```
namespace Core2AadAuth
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Adduser AddUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class Adduser
    {
        public bool accountEnabled { get; set; }
        public string creationType { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public Passwordprofile passwordProfile { get; set; }
        public Signinname[] signInNames { get; set; }
    }

    public class Passwordprofile
    {
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool forceChangePasswordNextLogin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Signinname
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But what I wanted to do is create an object of that class, add values to it and serialize it. The problem is that there are 4 separate classes. If I add them to one mother class that way, they won't be connected because I basically have 4 separate classes.

This is how I'm adding values to the object :

```
        Rootobject rootobject = new Rootobject();

        rootobject.AddUser.accountEnabled = true;
        rootobject.AddUser.creationType = "LocalAccount";
        rootobject.AddUser.displayName = "TestClassUser";
        rootobject.AddUser.passwordProfile.password = "TestClassUser";
        rootobject.AddUser.passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextLogin = false;


        Signinname userName = new Signinname();

        userName.type = "userName";
        userName.value = "TestClassUser";

        Signinname emailAddress = new Signinname();

        emailAddress.type = "emailAddress";
        emailAddress.value = "TestClassUser@Test.com";
```

I can't figure out how to pass data to Signinname class objects that are inside Adduser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create instances of those classes and set them against the properties of `Adduser` e.g.

```
Adduser adduser = new Adduser();

adduser.passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile() 
{
    password = "TestClassUser",
    forceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
};
adduser.signInNames = new Signinname[2] {
    new Signinname() 
    {
        type = "userName",
        value = "TestClassUser"
    },
    new Signinname()
    {
        type = "emailAddress",
        value = "TestClassUser@Test.com"
    }
};
```

Comment: I edited in the root at the beginning but yeah this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Qya no worries, FWIW pascal casing is recommended with C# class names so `Adduser` should be `AddUser`, `Signinname` should be `SignInName` etc. just makes for better readability.

Comment: Hm okay nevermind, VS says that the adduser.signInNames = [  part contains an invalid expression term [ . No idea how to approach this.

Comment: @Qya apologies, see update, still had my Node hat on (not wrote C# in a while).